# Keep user online while reading on page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In php for checking users status (online/offline) I use a code that runs on every page load and do an update on `last_activity` users column.
if `last_activity` is more than 5 minutes user will be offline and signed out.

But there is a problem with this code:

It runs on every page load, but if user do not reload page or load any pages, this code won't work and show him/her offline after 5 minutes reading a pagem in some cases maybe it takes 1 hour to read an article in a page and I want to show user online while user is reading a page too.

I thought maybe I can do it with mouse scrolling in JS but its impossible!

So anybody did this before or any solution for this? (In php or js/jquery)

Comment: `I thought maybe I can do it with mouse scrolling in JS but its impossible!` Not at all. Hook to the `scroll` event, then send an AJAX request to the server which keeps the session alive. If you want more specific help, please edit your question to include what you tried, because your question is too broad as it stands

Comment: you could use jQuery / AJAX to send POST request to server every 4 minutes which updates the last active time.

Comment: Use websockets, which can be server or client side, or async ajax requests every few minutes from the client. jQuery makes background ajax requests very easy.

Comment: You could do the ajax request on scroll or mousemove, and throttle it so that you are not firing off ajax requests constantly.

Comment: why not post these as answers they good ideas :P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930208/how-to-keep-extending-session-life-when-user-is-active

Comment: @Andrew because right now the question is too broad, and any answer given would be a full code write.

Comment: Using ajax request on mouse scrolling works but does it not make page load speed low? I mean when for example 100 users reading one page and scrolling it it makes 100 requests at a time! really its OK?

Comment: If your server can't handle 100 web requests, you have a server issue.  Also, the ajax request to update the activity time has nothing to do with what the user sees on the page.  Its invisible to them.

Comment: its not about just 100 requests in this page. its about all requests on website too. I think it maybe cause a problem if I have a lot of users! if its not let me know.

Comment: You could save the scroll position, and then use setInterval to check every minute (or as often as you want) if the scroll position has changed, if so, run the AJAX request to keep the session alive. That way you'd only be making the AJAX request at most once every X minutes for each user.